# CMake in BB Recipe

Tags: makefile, cmake, bitbake

I'm working on an OpenEmbedded Layer for [cpsumon](https://github.com/ka87/cpsumon), a tool written in C for monitoring Corsair AXi Power Supply Units (PSU).

Code for my layer can be found at https://github.com/bernardoaraujor/meta-cpsumon

My experience with Make and CMake is very limited, and I'm having trouble to understand the following error:

```
[bernardo@localhost build-genericx86-64]$ bitbake cpsumon
WARNING: Host distribution "fedora-27" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Loading cache: 100% |###############################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1312 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "genericx86-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.4.2"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 core2"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta-intel           = "rocko:49187e370e7d5370c7adc5a6f1b721b950667113"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "rocko:50189fdf620bc9ca42065998ce8c5a796ad8c331"
meta-mobiles         = "master:147a75c68e60392e3194c17371b447d1183fd8b7"
meta-cpsumon         = "master:281afc3077384716dd3954af4c43dfa76609bb81"
Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: cpsumon-git-r0 do_install: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/temp/log.do_install.3666)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/temp/log.do_install.3666
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['virtual:native:/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.65.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_1.8.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake/cmake-native_3.8.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.26.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_7.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_7.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: ['pseudo-native']
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['pkgconfig-native', 'quilt-native', 'cmake-native', 'glibc', 'gcc-cross-x86_64', 'gcc-runtime', 'automake-native', 'autoconf-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'libtool-native', 'expat-native', 'curl-native', 'bzip2-native', 'zlib-native', 'xz-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'libmpc-native', 'mpfr-native', 'linux-libc-headers', 'gmp-native', 'binutils-cross-x86_64', 'libgcc', 'm4-native', 'pigz-native', 'openssl-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'flex-native', 'bison-native', 'cryptodev-linux-native', 'makedepend-native', 'xproto-native', 'util-macros-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| NOTE: DESTDIR=/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/image cmake --build /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/build --target install -- -j 2
| make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
| WARNING: /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/temp/run.do_install.3666:1 exit 2 from 'DESTDIR='/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/image' cmake --build '/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/build' --target install -- -j 2'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/poky/build-genericx86-64/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/cpsumon/git-r0/temp/log.do_install.3666)
ERROR: Task (/home/bernardo/dev/yocto/meta-cpsumon/recipes-core/cpsumon/cpsumon_git.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
Second Keyboard Interrupt, stopping...

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/bernardo/dev/yocto/meta-cpsumon/recipes-core/cpsumon/cpsumon_git.bb:do_install
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
[bernardo@localhost build-genericx86-64]$
```

From what I understood, `| make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.` means BitBake is trying to execute cmall with `--target install`, and for some reason make can't execute the `install` task. Is that correct?

I don't understand whether the issue must be fixed in CMakeLists.txt or cpsumon_git.bb.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The CMake scripts for `cpsumon` don't actually install the library anywhere, so the generated makefiles do not contain an `install` target.

Thus, when the `do_install` task does `make install`, you get the error from `make` saying

`make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.`